# Wait for HTTP web request to finish before populating static table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, httpwebrequest

I have a static UITableView that I want to populate with data retrieved using an HTTP request (which runs asynchonously). I tried to make the HTTP request in several places but everytime the data from the request arrives too late and the table view is not populated. The only way I found to populate the table view is to call `reloadData` as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    _accountModel = [[CatapultAccount alloc] init];

    [_accountModel getCurrentClient:^ (BOOL completed, NSDictionary *currentAccount) {
        if (completed) {
            _account = currentAccount;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        } else {
            UIAlertView *errorMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Account retrieval unsuccessful"
                                                                   message:@"Unable to retrieve current account information"
                                                                  delegate:self
                                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                         otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [errorMessage show];
        }
    }];
}
```

I tried to make the request run on the main thread, but it seems that it already runs on the main thread… I suspect it's the actual request that is called from within `getCurrentClient` that runs in the background:

```
- (void)getCurrentClient:(void (^)(BOOL completed, NSDictionary *account))completion
{
    __block BOOL operationSuccessful = NO;
    __block NSDictionary *currentClient = nil;
    NXOAuth2Account *currentAccount = [[[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore] accounts] lastObject];

    [NXOAuth2Request performMethod:@"GET"
                        onResource:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/clients/%@", kCatapultHost, currentAccount.userData[@"account_name"]]]
                   usingParameters:nil
                       withAccount:currentAccount
               sendProgressHandler:nil
                   responseHandler:^ (NSURLResponse *response, NSData *responseData, NSError *error) {
                       if (error != nil) {
                           operationSuccessful = NO;
#if DEBUG
                           NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
#endif
                       }
                       else {
                           operationSuccessful = YES;

                           NSError *jsonError;

                           currentClient = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                                            options:kNilOptions
                                                                              error:&jsonError];

                           if (jsonError != nil) {
                               operationSuccessful = NO;
#if DEBUG
                               NSLog(@"Error: %@", jsonError);
#endif
                           }
                       }

                       completion(operationSuccessful, currentClient);
                   }];
}
```

So is my approach (calling reloadData) the good one? Isn't there a way to make the table view controller wait for the request to finish?

Comment: Have you tried putting the call to `reloadData` in your response handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't make table view controller wait. Calling reload data is a normal pattern on a callback from a web service. There isn't a lot you can do if you're waiting for a network call to complete before display some data.. here are some ideas...

You might show a progress indicator whilst it is loading.

Alternatively, if you have another view controller prior to this one, you could press a buttton which triggers loading your data, and when the request completes it pushes the new table view controller onto the screen with the data ready.

More advanced would be to use key value observing (KVO) on a model object. Your table would use the model object as its data source. You load from the network and populate the model object with the results. KVO would handle notifying the static table that new data has arrived and it should display it (instead of doing a reload of the whole table)... however you will still have a blank state at the start.